# Почему asm.js влияет на будущее js?

Tags: javascript

Смотрю [предложение по добавлению BigInt в javascript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint). Там целый [раздел](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint#dont-break-asmjs) посвящён совместимости с asm.js. И именно из-за этого отказываются от унарного плюса с новым типом - asm.js предполагает, что унарный плюс возвращает Number или падает.

Asm.js играет какую-то особую роль для джаваскрипта и браузеров? Почему именно его следует учитывать особенным образом и отказываться от логичного унарного плюса с новым числовым типом данных?

Comment: asm.js не умер? o_O

Comment: @andreymal, asm.js используется как фоллбэк WebAssembly (когда браузер не поддерживает wasm) - они прямые родственники. Так что, получается, не умер.